# Parse xml data using sax parser in java

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sax

I want to parse xml data which is as follows

xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers>
    <setMarker id="56c6b9c4ef263869678b4567" mlat="12.947014112057" mlng="77.62656211853"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6b9c5ef263869678b4568" mlat="12.941744189945" mlng="77.628879547119"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6ba01ef263805688b4567" mlat="12.929865544388" mlng="77.633428573608"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6ba11ef2638c3668b4569" mlat="12.93630685197" mlng="77.613000869751"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6ba1aef263814688b4567" mlat="12.944755587651" mlng="77.617979049683"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6ba2bef26383e678b4567" mlat="12.928359760197" mlng="77.609052658081"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6ba39ef263804678b4568" mlat="12.917317065284" mlng="77.60853767395"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6ba3eef263849678b4567" mlat="12.908783739405" mlng="77.609825134277"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6ba4eef263852678b4567" mlat="12.917735358079" mlng="77.586135864258"
        slot_id="morning" />
    <setMarker id="56c6ba58ef26383e678b4568" mlat="12.929196308091" mlng="77.583990097046"
        slot_id="morning" />
</marker>
```

but when I am parsing it is giving null value for each field. Although parser works fine when this format of xml is given-

working format-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<markers>
    <setMarker>
        <mlat>"2163</mlat>
        <mlng>Kumar</mlng>
        <slot_id>Development</slot_id>

    </setMarker>
    <setMarker>
        <mlat>6752</mlat>
        <mlng>Siva</mlng>
        <slot_id>DB</slot_id>

    </setMarker>
    <setMarker>
        <mlat>6763</mlat>
        <mlng>Timmy</mlng>
        <slot_id>Testing</slot_id>

    </setMarker>
</markers>
```

How do I parse the xml data in that format using sax parser?

Answer (score 0):

The XML format which you say does not yield expected results has values as attributes. Try reading the values using the Attribute class method - getValue().

Comment: this is the link to actual question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707699/getting-null-values-after-parsing-xml-file-using-sax-parser-in-android
can you tell me where exactly i have to use that method. @Anirudh

Answer (score 0):

Access element attributes like so.

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("setMarker")){
        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
        String mlat = attributes.getValue("mlat");
        String mlng = attributes.getValue("mlng");
        String slot_id = attributes.getValue("slot_id");
    }
}
```